# Proving a function $\mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_m,\ [a] \mapsto [a^2 + 3a + 1]$ is well defined

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

> Prove that $\operatorname{poly}\colon \mathbb{Z}_m \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ given by $\operatorname{poly}\colon [a] \mapsto [a^2 + 3a + 1]$ is well defined.

---

This is what I have so far, working in (mod m)

i.e. if $a' \equiv a$ then $a'^2+3a'+1 \equiv a^2 + 3a + 1$. ( need to prove)

Since $a' \equiv a$, there exists $d$ such that $dm = a' -a$

Not sure where to go from here, any tips?

Comment: You can always compute $a^2+3a+1 \bmod m$ for any $a$. So I'm not sure what you mean by "well-defined".

Comment: Needed to show that using 'different' but congruent equivalent classes (e.g. $[16]$ and $[6]$ as inputs would yield the same output, since $[16] \equiv [6]$ (mod $5$)). And showing that same inputs would not yield different outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(a^2+3a+1)-(a'^2+3a'+1)=(a-a')(a+a'+3)$.

Thus, if $(a-a')$ is a multiple of $m$, then so is $(a^2+3a+1)-(a'^2+3a'+1)$.

Comment: This is extremely slick and generalizes to all polynomials, if I'm not mistaken! Nicely done.

Comment: Yep, if $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $(x-y)\vert (p(x)-p(y))$, so it generalises nicely to all polynomials with integer coefficients, as well as all moduli.

Answer (score 2):

So in your expression $a′^2 +3a ′ +1$, replace $a'$ with $a+dm$, and factor out.  What you should get should be congruent to $a^2 +3a+1$ (mod $m$).